# How to copy range of cells using inputbox and paste to newly created sheet

Tags: vba, excel

It's my 1st time here and needed some help. not good with coding as I just started with the help of youtube. I saw a post here that helps you create sheets with VBA. and this is what i started on. MAybe you can help me along the way.

```
Sub cutcell()

Dim number, name As Variant

'ask the number of cell and name of new sheet

number = InputBox("Number of cells to cut")
name = InputBox("Name of new sheet")

' select Cell from A1 to the number of sheet inputted
Range("A1:A(number)").Select
Selection Cut

'creates a new worksheet
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = name.Value ' renames the new worksheet
Range("A1").Select
activeheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to improve your question as it isn't a question! What is the problem? What do you want help with? The more you explain, the better the help you will get.

Comment: Hi Rob, the problem is. its not working. the code is imcomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Sub cutcell()
Dim wsNew As Worksheet
Dim RngToCut As Range
Dim number, NewName As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'ask the number of cell and name of new sheet
number = Application.InputBox("Number of cells to cut", Type:=1)    'This will only allow a number input

If number = 0 Then
    MsgBox "You didn't enter  number.", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

Set RngToCut = Range("A1:A" & number)

'Ask user to input name of the New Sheet
NewName = InputBox("Name of new sheet")

If NewName = "" Then
    MsgBox "You didn't input the name of New Sheet.", vbCritical, "New Sheet Name Missing!"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
wsNew.name = NewName

RngToCut.Cut wsNew.Range("A1")
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks sktneer. everyone here is awesome

Comment: What will you do if the user enters "ttt" or some other string in he number section? If you want to add error handling, at least use the Application.InputBox

Comment: @ShaiRado Please look the code. For number input I have already used Application.InputBox. ;) Also do you remember there is no end of If and buts as I mentioned it in another question. :)

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks both of you. now that it worked. i want to try if it can be automatic. i'll have 1 sheet with the names of my team mate. and the other sheet with the cases that we will work on. which is equally divided. is it possible? like if i have 10 names on sheet1 and all the cases will be on sheet2 (1000 cases). when i hit the button. it will create 10 new sheets with our names. and the cases will automatically divided to the 10 of us (100 each)? thanks in advance

Comment: @Leeoneal I don't understand your behavior. Why did you deselect the answer? Are you not clear about which solution would work for you?

Comment: @sktneer i apologize for deselecting. i didnt know that you can only choose one. noob here hehe

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
Range("A1:A(number)").Select
```

You need to work out the range but putting it in quotes takes it as literally what you say. Try this:

```
Range("A1:A" + number).Select
```

Another problem is here:

```
activeheet.Paste
```

You have misspelled ActiveSheet. Try:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: i just need to figure out the naming of the new sheet it will go to

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you stay away from `Select`, `Selection` and `ActiveSheet`, and instead use fully qualified `Range` and `Worksheets` objects.

Read here [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) .

Also, the Cut>>Paste is a 1-line syntax (see code below), just try to keep the 2 actions as close as can be (create the new `Worksheet` object before this action).

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub cutcell()

Dim number As Long, name As String
Dim OrigSht As Worksheet
Dim NewSht As Worksheet

'ask the number of cell and name of new sheet
number = InputBox("Number of cells to cut")
name = InputBox("Name of new sheet")

' save the currebt active sheet
Set OrigSht = ActiveSheet ' <-- I still prefer to use Worksheets("SheetName")

' first create the new worksheet
Set NewSht = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
NewSht.name = name ' renames the new worksheet

' select Cell from A1 to the number of sheet inputted , use Cut>>Paste in 1 line
OrigSht.Range("A1:A" & number).Cut Destination:=NewSht.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Super Thanks Shai

Comment: Sub AddSheets2()
  
Dim myRange2, sheetname As Variant
   
myRange2 = InputBox("Please Select a Range")
        
Range("A1:A" + myRange2).Select
Selection.Cut
               
sheetname = InputBox("Name of new sheet")
 
 
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
Sheets(Sheets.Count).name = sheetname
ActiveSheet.Paste
 
End Sub

Comment: this is what I did. but yours is way more better and clean looking

Answer (score 0):

A inputbox type 8 could be used for that purpose, since it lets user pick the desired range.

You might find other examples in here.

Cris

Comment: thanks cris. that was the 1st thing i tried. i want the user to just input the number of cells he wants withouht looking at the sheet. but thanks though